# See session variables from different sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Lets say browser `A` logs in to my website creating new session. Then browser `B` logs in to the same website creating another session. Is there a way that I can see browser's A session variable from browser's `B` session?

---

Edit.

I guess my question is if I have `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID` stored on my database from browser A. Knowing that id, how can I retrieve that session. I have tried things like:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetSession(browserAsessionId);
```

Comment: Do you know the ID of the first browser's session from requests from the second browser?  You'd have to figure that out yourself after all.

Comment: is it global ? then create static variables instead of session

Comment: If you know Session ID, then you can query SessionProvider with that ID to get session data of other session

Comment: Are you _wanting_ to do that or are you trying to determine if `Session` is _secure_?

Comment: Yes I can store the first browswer's ID on the database. So I guess the answer to that question is I need the session id?

Comment: Asking about how to access another user's session sounds like you are asking how to do something nefarious. You may not get very much assistance with this kind of request, consider rephrasing it.

Comment: @StingyJack This is all server side stuff, not client side stuff.  If someone's in the position where they're executing code on someone else's server they've already lost, hard, and accessing various user's session data isn't likely the best use of one's time when you've gotten to the point of running code on someone else's server.  it sounds like he, as the dev of the site, wants to do something based on the session data of multiple users.  (Say, try and merge together multiple sessions that a single user has created.)  It certainly doesn't sound nefarious.

Comment: What type of session state are you using? InProc, SQL Session, State Server?